# Determining if the given system is LTI

Tags: signal-analysis, continuous-signals, linear-systems

### Problem

> Given the compound system below, with the input $x(t)=\operatorname{sinc(t)}$, the output of *A* is $y(t)=\operatorname{sinc(2t)}$ and the output of *B* is $z(t)=\operatorname{sinc(t)}$, determine which of the A, B systems are Linear time invariant (LTI).
>   [image]
>
> - a) A
> - b) B
> - c) Both
> - d) Neither

### My approach:

Using two facts below (if I got them right):

- A and B are inverse of each other (because the overall output is
  equal to the input)
- If an LTI system is reversible, then the reverse is also LTI.

after a quick scanning I crossed ***a, b*** as the answered. I concluded that either both systems are `LTI` or neither of them are.

For the next step, using the given information I derived the system A:

\begin{align}
x(t)&=\frac {\sin(\pi t)}{\pi t}\\
y(t)&=\frac {\sin(2\pi t)}{\pi t}=\frac{2\sin(\pi t)\cos(\pi t)}{\pi t}=\frac{2\sin(\pi t)\sin(\pi t+\frac{\pi}{2})}{\pi t}=2\pi t x(t)x\left(t+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
\end{align}

now with the $t$ as the coefficient of the system we can say $y$ is not time invariant and therfore not `LTI`. so I chose ***d*** as the correct answer.
But the text book I'm reading proves that ***b*** is the answer, using another method.

### Questions:

So my questions are:

- Is my approach/facts flawed?
- If so, what is the correct approach to solve this problem.
- OR possibly did the book get it wrong?

Any help would be highly apprecieted!

Comment: What's quite flawed about your approach is the idea that a single such simple pair of input and output signals would give you conclusive information about whether a system is LTI. Really, you can _never_ prove something is LTI by simply looking at a given input and output, only _disprove_ that a system is LTI. (Though in practice, if you compare the power spectrums for many different signals and notice that the output for each frequence is always same same frequency-wise multiple of the same frequency in the input, this is a good indication that the system may well be LTI).

Comment: @Amen could you say the name of the book you are learning from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I would approach the problem.

System $A$ cannot be LTI because its output has frequencies not present in its input. The input spectrum is a brickwall from $f=-1/2$ to $f=1/2$, but the output spectrum is a brickwall from $f=-1$ to $f=1$.

It's impossible to arrive at a conclusion for system B. It *could* be an ideal LTI low-pass filter, but it could also be something else (for example, it could be a signal generator).

Note that we cannot say that A and B are inverses of each other. That statement requires $x(t)=B[A[x(t)]]$ to be true for *all* $x(t)$. Here, we only know that is true for one specific input.

Comment: Can we use my two facts to conclude that system B is not LTI as well?

Comment: by the way the book exactly used  your approach for the system A and reversed this logic to state B **is**  LTI.

Comment: I don't think so -- B _could_ be LTI. However, given the information we have, there's no way to tell.

Comment: @Amen, please see my edit. We can't be sure A and B are inverses.